# Is there a way to mark all posts as unread in Google Reader?

Tags: google-reader, rss

I'm looking for a way to mark all items from a specific RSS feed as unread in Google Reader.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: It is a damn shame such a major piece of functionality is missing. You can't even un-do marking them all as read. This feature is sorely missed when you add a new feed that you've never read and it presumes you're only interested in the last 30 posts by marking all others as read.

Comment: This is really surprising.  I've quickly come to love Google Reader, but not being able to do this is a pain.  Does anyone know a good alternative to Google Reader, where you are allowed to do this?

Answer (score 6):

I don't believe there is. I've looked a few times and never found a way to do it

Answer (score 1):

You can't mark multiple posts in Google Reader as "unread". You have to do it one by one.

The only recourse you have is to turn on [keyboard shortcuts](http://support.google.com/reader/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=69973) and go through the list tapping <kbd>j</kbd> <kbd>m</kbd> to mark all that you can as unread.

But before you can unmark as read, when viewing the feed, select **Items older than two weeks** from the "Mark all as read" menu to allow for this.

Any older and you're left just looking at them in a "read" state.